# How to Unlock NEMESIS in Final Fantasy X?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

How can we Unlock the BOSS NEMESIS at the Arena (Calm Lands)?

And also what suggested characteristics the combat team should have and what formation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://faqs.ign.com/articles/750/750274p1.html) article,

> you have to capture 10 of EVERY fiend
>   in the entire game... then you have to
>   beat all of the Area Conquest, Species
>   Conquest and Original monsters in the
>   arena.

Also provided are preparation tactics:

> you MUST have weapons that have Break
>   Damage Limit and One MP Cost, armor
>   with Auto-  Phoenix and Auto-Haste
>   would be nice too. Have the
>   person/people with One MP Cost know
>   Auto Life so the others do not have to
>   waste precious MP casting it. Quick
>   Attack is also helpful.

Comment: I have captured all the fiends in the game. But you said I will have to defeat all Area Conquest, Species Conquest and Original monsters in the arena??? Whoa!! But is Nemesis worth UNLOCKING?? is it that much fun??

Comment: Whether or not you feel it's worth it is up to you

Answer (score 1):

Nemesis is the final boss of the Arena post-game and arguably the hardest boss in the game with the exception of Penance. It is unlocked by capturing 10 of every fiend then beating every area, species, and original creation at least once.

Unlocking Nemesis rewards 99 Dark Matter, which is enough to customise Ribbon onto an armor.

The ideal party includes Rikku and Wakka. Rikku's Mix- specifically Hyper Mighty G- is the strongest support ability in the game. Wakka's Overdrive Attack Reels deals the most damage (1,199,988 with perfect, celestial, and Strength).

The best third character for the post game is Tidus but it matters less. Swapping him for Yuna is fine if you can't beat the chocobo minigame.

All characters should have their celestial weapons as they ignore nemesis' defence stat. Statwise, 255 strength and 170 agility (the cap) are strongly recommended. Luck is not necessary to hit here. Magic is pointless in most cases. Other stats depend on your strategy- what attacks do you plan on surviving? Nemesis has the following moves:

- Attack- Survivable with protect, high defense and 9999 hp, single target
- Ethereal cannon- survivable with shell, magic defense, and 9999 hp, single target
- Ultima- counterattack to being hit by anthing besides attacks, skills, or magic- such as Attack Reels. Survivable with shell and magic defense
- Ultra Spark- Always deals 10k+ damage. Needs auto-life or break hp limit
- Armageddon- Always deals 99999 damage. Needs auto-life or an aeon.

If you are playing without break hp limit, you need Auto-Haste and Auto-Phoenix. There are options for the other 2 slots- you don't need stoneproof or ribbon here but it depends on how many sets of armour you have the patience to farm for. The standard endgame Auto-Protect + Ribbon/Stoneproof is fine though Auto-Potion is also an option.

If you are playing with break hp limit, you will have 99999 hp and maxed defenses. The armor in that case will be Auto-Haste, Ribbon (if you farm 99999 hp, you can farm 2 ribbon armours), and Auto-Regen.

The fight itself revolves around mixing Hyper Mighty G or casting auto-life at any point where the boss might use Ultra Spark (if not breaking HP limit) or Armageddon.